# Multiple Joins - Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, join

I have three tables:

Table A (approx. 500 000 records)

| ID | ID_B | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | bla |
| 2 | 10 | blabla |
| 3 | 30 | blablabla |

Table B (approx. 100 000 records)

| ID | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | blab |
| 20 | blaba |
| 30 | blabb |

Table C (approx. 600 000 records)

| ID | ID_A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

Now I want to join this three tables:

```
SELECT A.Text
FROM A
     JOIN B ON B.ID = A.ID_B 
     JOIN C ON C.ID_A = A.ID
```

I have created a clustered primary key index (ID) and non-clustered index (ID_B) on table A.

According to the execution plan, at the beginning the clustered index is used to join A and C.
Afterwards the result set is sorted on column ID_B and used then in a merge join with B.

[Execution Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aap7n.png)

The sort operation is the most expensive one. (about 40% of total costs)

Is there any way to optimize this query in terms of overall performance?

Comment: Why `JOIN` when you only want one column from one table?

Comment: Show us your execution plan using "Paste The Plan"

Comment: @Larnu could be that only results should be included where there are fk relations (could also be accomplished by use of exists). Obviously just a guess on my part given the limited information.

Comment: @Larnu: because I don't need all the rows from A

Comment: Then why not use an `EXISTS`?

Comment: As you only want columns from A, use `exists`

Comment: You mean A is scanned using a clustered index for matching values against C - ( I bet that C would default to a *table scan* without a key including ID_A ), then the two tables would have to be matched on the inner join operation.

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a better way to include an execution plan in your question. Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't mentioned if you have any indexes on table B.  Perhaps an index on it with the identifier and 'including' any columns you want to output.

Now, from what I gather in the comments, you're really joining to tables b and c primarily as a filter, not because you need to output data from those tables.  If that's really the case, you should use `exists`.  You may shy away from subqueries, but the engine knows what to do with `exists`.  You'll see in the plan that it will run a 'semi join'.

```
select    a.text
from      a
where     exists (select 0 from b where b.id = a.id_b) 
and       exists (select 0 from c where c.id_a = a.id)
```